# Add a navigation bar to a view in code, without a navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a problem with my nav bar in Swift. I move from one view controller to another like this:

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameViewController") as GameViewController
nextViewController.transitioningDelegate = self.transitionManager
self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

But when I see my second view controller, it disappears. I can't use a segue here.

How do I add a navigation bar, with a bar button item, without a Navigation controller in Swift?

I saw this: [Add a navigation bar to a view without a navigation controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23859785/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you can use IB: drag a `Navigation Bar` from the left pane onto your `UIViewController`. As shown in the picture:

[image]

To make the `Navigation Bar` size correctly depending on the device, you need to add constraints to pin the top edge to the top of the view and both the left and right edges to the left and right of the view (the height is intrinsic and doesn't need a constraint). This can also be done in IB:

[image]

Once you've done these two steps you can use the `Navigation Bar` just like you would normally - for example I've added a `Bar Button Item` to the `Navigation Bar` in the first image.

Comment: Thx for this answer but I will clarify. I want it in code