# Adding Navigation Item in UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to add UINavigationItem to my UIViewController as mentioned [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23859785/how-to-add-navigation-bar-to-a-view-without-navigation-controller/#24681152). However the Navigation bar is not showing in my view. I tried even adding an outlet and setting the title programmatically and also adding the NavigationItem in two different places. Still it doesn't show. This view controller is embedded in a TabBarController. WHat am I missing here?

[image: Storyboard image]

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This view controller is embedded in a TabBarController

But is it embedded, first and foremost, in a UINavigationController? If not, there will be no navigation bar that automatically appears and that automatically uses your view controller's navigation item.

If you don't want to use a UINavigationController (because you have no navigation to do), then you can add a navigation bar manually. But in that case your view controller's navigation item will not be used automatically to populate the navigation bar; you must populate it manually.

Typically, people *do* use a UINavigationController, even if there is no navigation to do, just to get this automatic behavior - to show the navigation bar and to populate it automatically.

[NOTE: The fact that you have told Interface Builder to *show* a navigation bar for this view controller, *as if* it were in a navigation controller, is irrelevant; that won't cause you to get any navigation bar when the app runs.]

Comment: No, It is not embedded in a UINavigationController. I will try as you have suggested and let you know. Thank you Matt!

Comment: I tried embedding my UIViewController in a UINavigationController and works as expected. Thank you!

Comment: I'm happy to help! You might want to read the explanation of navigation controllers in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_navigation_controllers Basically you've encountered the thing I don't like about storyboards: they give you a lot of power, but they do not relieve of you of responsibility for understanding how these things really work and what you are really doing.

Comment: @matt This is also what I hate about iOS. I love the way Android chose to design their UI framework, which offers you tiny building blocks to do everything you want to do easily. iOS tries to do *everything* for you, while it still does not do it well after many years, it tries to *keep you updated* with each release of Xcode, and they shamelessly call those *updates* improvements.

Comment: @neevek Yes, your comment reminds me of the rant I inserted into my book the year that storyboards were introduced. I took out the rant in later editions, but I thought (and still think) they were a bad idea, because they invited beginners to use them as a crutch (to "do everything for you", as you put it) without understanding what they were really doing behind the scenes. And the kinds of questions that get asked every day on Stack Overflow prove that I was absolutely right about that. :)

Comment: @matt Indeed, and there's one thing that proved Apple to be absolutely wrong, each major release of Xcode introduced some *improvements* and *features*, or *modern technology* for you to learn. And let's take a look at the Android camp, the way we design UI for Android **never** changed since it was introduced in 2008. That is irony and quite unfortunate for developers.