# Header on view controller with default modalPresentationStyle - iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I would like to add a title and action button to a view controller with the default modalPresentationStyle in iOS 13. See the example from the alarm app for context.

[image: Apple Alarm example]

I am presenting a view controller as follows:

```
let vc = TestViewController()
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Elsewhere in my app, I use `self.navigationItem.title` to set the title. This doesn't work in this situation, as I am doing `self.present` to show the new view controller and not `self.navigationController?.pushViewController`.

How can I add a title like the alarm app has?

Comment: You can add a `UINavigationBar` to your view controller, just like you add a label or button or view, etc. It doesn't have to be part of a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: This worked. I used this s/o post for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23859785/add-a-navigation-bar-to-a-view-without-a-navigation-controller

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let vc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: TestViewController())
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen // if you want to present it in full screen mode
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

in viewDidLoad of presented Controller add title and the navigationBarButton with the action:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "yourButtonTitle", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(functionTocall))
navigationItem.title = "yourTitle"
```

If I understand the problem correctly, this should solve it

Comment: I needed the display type to be default, not .fullScreen. @DonMag's comment pointed me in the right direction

Comment: ok, but if you don't want a full screen presentation you simply delete the vc.modalPresentationStyle line... :)